# ASP.NET Stop re-load whole page when click a button?

Tags: asp.net, calendar

[image]

So when I click the Select button, the calendar will be appeared and I can select a date, then disappear after I selected a date. Problem is that every time I click the button the whole page is re-loaded, is there any way to prevent it?

I am a newbie with ASP.NET? Here is the design code and the actual code for event:

```
        <tr>
<td>
    Expired Date
</td>
            <td>

                <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnSelectDate" runat="server" OnClick="btnSelectDate_Click" Text="Select" />
&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnClearDate" runat="server" OnClick="btnClearDate_Click" Text="Clear" />
            </td><td></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
<td>
    &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Calendar ID="calExpiredDate" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="1" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#003399" Height="200px" Visible="False" Width="220px" OnSelectionChanged="calExpiredDate_SelectionChanged">
                    <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" Height="1px" />
                    <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
                    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
                    <SelectorStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" />
                    <TitleStyle BackColor="#003399" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" Height="25px" />
                    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="White" />
                    <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" />
                </asp:Calendar>
                <br />
            </td><td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
```

---

```
protected void btnSelectDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (calExpiredDate.Visible == false) calExpiredDate.Visible = true;
            else calExpiredDate.Visible = false;
        }

        protected void btnClearDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtExpDate.Text = null;
        }


        protected void calExpiredDate_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtExpDate.Text = calExpiredDate.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
            calExpiredDate.Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: Either use [`ASP.NET-Ajax`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution is to wrap everything in an `<asp:UpdatePanel>`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
    <ContentTemplate>
        your content, buttons, html, etc
    </ContentTemplate
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

It will block the page flicker for you.

Comment: I put all of those textbox, buttons and calendar inside UpdatePanel and now when I click a button nothing happened?

Comment: OK I figured out it only works if others text-boxes (I have several text-boxes in the form, all of those required to fill) have been fulfilled, in other words all other valid control should be valid. How to make it to ignore other controls?

Comment: Turn off CausesValidation

Answer (score 0):

Do as Garrison Neely suggested, then for those text boxes you don't want to validate, set 'CausesValidation' property to 'False'.